# Why I am not getting passed values at another Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, null

I am sending values using `intent.putExtras` but I am getting null values on the next activity. Here is my code for intent

```
if (id == R.id.save_times) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AlertTimerSelector.this, Dashboard.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppHelper.LOW_LEVEL, dialogHelper.getPicker_value1());
        Log.d("AlertTimer", "onOptionsItemSelected: " + dialogHelper.getPicker_value1());
        intent.putExtra(AppHelper.MEDIUM_LEVEL, dialogHelper.getPicker_value2());
        Log.d("AlertTimer", "onOptionsItemSelected: " + dialogHelper.getPicker_value2());
        intent.putExtra(AppHelper.HIGH_LEVEL, dialogHelper.getPicker_value3());
        Log.d("AlertTimer", "onOptionsItemSelected: " + dialogHelper.getPicker_value3());
        intent.putExtra(AppHelper.ALERT_TIME_ID_TEXT,AppHelper.ALERT_TIME_ID);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
```

And this is my next Activity code where i am retrieving these values in `onNewIntent`

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle.getString(AppHelper.ALERT_TIME_ID_TEXT).equals(AppHelper.ALERT_TIME_ID)){
        low_level_time=bundle.getString(AppHelper.LOW_LEVEL);
        medium_level_time=bundle.getString(AppHelper.MEDIUM_LEVEL);
        high_level_time=bundle.getString(AppHelper.HIGH_LEVEL);
    }
    if (bundle.get(AppHelper.SLEEP_TIME_ID_TEXT).equals(AppHelper.SLEEP_ID)){
        sleep_time_hrs=bundle.getString(AppHelper.SLEEP_TIME_HOURS);
        sleep_time_mins=bundle.getString(AppHelper.SLEEP_TIME_MINUTES);
        wakeup_time_hrs=bundle.getString(AppHelper.WAKEUP_TIME_HOURS);
        wakeup_time_mins=bundle.getString(AppHelper.WAKEUP_TIME_MINUTES);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent: "+bundle.toString());
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

please help me out with this.Thanx

onNewIntent is not getting called.I don't know why?

Comment: is your onNewIntent getting called?

Comment: Why not using `Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();` instead of `Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();` ?

Comment: @Amy no onNewIntent is not getting called

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK ok i will try it n let u know if it works thnx

Comment: then move you onNewIntent code to onCreate

Comment: @Amy i have to launch this activity twice so is it possible to write this code in onCreate

Comment: @Amy no it produces nullpointerexception when first time that activity launches

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK `Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();` is also not working. onNewIntent is not getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get your data for example on the `onCreate` method like this

```
String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra(AppHelper.LOW_LEVEL);
```

`OnNewIntent` is called when you try to start the same activity that has a launchmode equal to `singleTop` (or have it setted programmatically)

For extra information [read this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 1):

First, get the intent which has started your activity using the getIntent() method:

**Intent intent = getIntent();**

If your extra data is represented as strings, then you can use intent.getStringExtra(String name) method. In your case:

**String id = intent.getStringExtra(AppHelper.LOW_LEVEL);**

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 Intent intent=getIntent();
 if(intent!=null)
  {
    low_level_time=intent.getStringExtra(AppHelper.LOW_LEVEL);
     //other values like above..

  }
```

Comment: @UserSharma you are testing it now?

Answer (score 0):

**onNewIntent()** will be called only when **FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP** is called. Since you are using 3 flags in activity, there may be some problem. Use only **FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP** and try.

or

Move your values retrieving code to **onCreate** and try.

Answer (score 0):

The activity in which you are receiving intent,add the flag in manifest file under that activity

```
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: Still onNewIntent in not called

Comment: use the intent of Method onNewIntent method instead of getIntent().getExtras(); use intent.getExtras();